# How to send order email only to Admin ? (V 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders, customer, email

By default, when a customer buys something on my website (Magento 1.9) he receives an order confirmation via email.
The thing is I'm using another platform to send my emails to the customer.
So I don't want magento to send emails to the customer. I want to be the only one (the admin) notified when someone buys something.

So how can I make magento to send order email only to the admin and not the customer ?
Maybe I have to modify some files, but I dont know which one...

I really need some help. Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

New order email are sent when the method `Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php:queueNewOrderEmail` is called.

*If you look this method, you will see that there is a configuration setting `sales_email/order/enabled` to enable/disable this email but it seems that you don't want to disable it.*

To modify the destination email, I guess you will have to rewrite the `Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` and its method `queueNewOrderEmail`.

In your rewritten method, you will have to replace `$emailInfo->addTo($this->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);` by `$emailInfo->addTo(<the-email-you-want>, <the-name-you-want>);`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think we are getting close to the solution, but unfortunately it is not working. The emails are still being sent to the customer...

Comment: Do you have any other idea @Julien ?

Answer (score 0):

simply go to your magento admin panel >> system >> configuration >> sales >> transactions emails >> order >> set to unable. This way, the system will not shoot an emails after a new order is processed. Do the same for other stuffs like order updated and so

Comment: Its not the right solution because no emails will be sent not even to the admin. And I want to be the only one notified when someone place an order

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question but for Magento 2.x?
I'd like to send order email to admin, preferably without changing core files.
Any one got ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

for magento 2.4, use prefernce in di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" />
</config>
```

after prepareTemplate, update customer email with admin email

```
<?PHP

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Email\Sender;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder;

class OrderSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
{
protected function checkAndSend(Order $order)
{
    $this->identityContainer->setStore($order->getStore());
    if (!$this->identityContainer->isEnabled()) {
        return false;
    }
    $this->prepareTemplate($order);

    //could local admin email address from backend config
    $this->identityContainer->setCustomerEmail('ADMIN_EMAIL_ADDRESS');

    /** @var SenderBuilder $sender */
    $sender = $this->getSender();

    try {
        $sender->send();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    if ($this->identityContainer->getCopyMethod() == 'copy') {
        try {
            $sender->sendCopyTo();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```